# What is the correct syntax for a post url to Google Sheets which includes an API key?

Tags: google-sheets-api, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to post data to a Google Sheet (via a Gravity Forms form submission in WordPress).
My post url looks like this:
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1S45-------w3u1A/values:batchUpdate&key=AI-------KxIiBcD8
But I get this response:

```
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
```

**404.** Thatâ€™s an error.

The requested URL `/v4/spreadsheets/1S45-----3u1A/values:batchUpdate&key=AI----KxIiBcD8` was not found on this server.  Thatâ€™s all we know.

Comment: In your endpoint, the query parameter is not correct. `&` is `?`. But, unfortunately, at Google APIs, POST method cannot be used with API key. Please use the access token at the request header. This is the specification at Google side. Also, when you want to use the method of values.batchUpdate in Sheets API, the request body is required to be added. Can you provide your current request body? By the way, in your case, if the request body is small size, Web Apps of Google Apps Script, which can be used with GET method, might be useful. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike! This is great information. How can I see an example of using Google Apps Script to authenticate?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the settings I have now for the Gravity Forms Webhook API add on:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0aefztud34psvk1/webhooks%20%E2%80%B9%20forms%20%E2%80%B9%20wordpress%20%E2%80%94%20wordpress%202020-04-07%2019-28-32.png?dl=0
What is the key name in the request header?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Google Apps Script to authenticate`. From your image of replying, I could understand that you want to achieve your goal using Sheets API and you cannot show the sample request body. In this case, about the request header, please use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and service account. This can be seen at [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). The access token is not the API key. Please be careful this.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the log! Here it is:

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Your English is fine! Sorry for not posting the log! Here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/csqre0rdurqn9jt/%3Awp-content%3Auploads%3Agravity_forms%3Alogs%3Agravityform.png?dl=0 I just added header fields for private_key_id, client_email and client_id. Here's a scvreenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ubfxgekfhs653b/webhooks%20%E2%80%B9%20forms%20%E2%80%B9%20%202020-04-07%2019-53-37.png?dl=0.  But I still got an error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wl87mjox7xkkl3a/%3Awp-content%3Auploads%3Agravity_forms%3Alogs%3A.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I cannot understand about your current detail situation from your replying, from 2nd image, it is found that you don't use access token. In order to retrieve access token, it is required to retrieve the refresh token. By this, access token can be refreshed, because the expiration time of it is 1 hour. This can be seen at [this document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). So in your situation, at first, the refresh token is required to be retrieved. But I'm not sure whether this flow can be directly run in your situation. How about this?